# Using media player in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

**What i am doing:** I am playing a media player from a url

**What is happening:** In the beginning, the screen is like unresponsive and hangs since the song buffering is happening.

**Question:**

1. How to overcome this ?
2. Should i need to use a Async task here instead of handler ? ... if
   so how to modify the code i have posted
3. Or should i just need to show a progress dialog here. in handler ?
   ... is possible ? .. if so how ?

**Code:**

```
protected void newValue(TextView txtSrcId, TextView txtDstId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            do {
                current = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                System.out.println("duration - " + duration + " current- "
                        + current);
                int dSeconds = (int) (duration / 1000) % 60 ;
                int dMinutes = (int) ((duration / (1000*60)) % 60);
                int dHours   = (int) ((duration / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

                int cSeconds = (int) (current / 1000) % 60 ;
                int cMinutes = (int) ((current / (1000*60)) % 60);
                int cHours   = (int) ((current / (1000*60*60)) % 24);


                if(dHours == 0){
                    txtSrcId.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", cMinutes, cSeconds));
                    txtDstId.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", dMinutes, dSeconds));
                    //txtSrcId.setText("jodwjdwudwudguwdgwugduwgduwgduwgd");
                }else{
                    txtSrcId.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",cHours, cMinutes, cSeconds));
                    txtDstId.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",dHours, dMinutes, dSeconds));
                    //txtSrcId.setText("jodwjdwudwudguwdgwugduwgduwgduwgd");
                }

                try{
                    Log.d("Value: ", String.valueOf((int) (current * 100 / duration)));
                    if(seekBarProgress.getProgress() >= 100){
                        break;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {}
            }while (seekBarProgress.getProgress() <= 100);
        }


        private Runnable onEverySecond = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                if(true == running){
                    if(seekBarProgress != null) {
                        seekBarProgress.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    }

                    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        seekBarProgress.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
                        //updateTime();
                        newValue(txtSrcId,txtDstId);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        public void play() {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
            seekBarProgress.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);

        } 


        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            seekBarProgress.setMax(duration);
            seekBarProgress.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            /** Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song loading from URL position*/
            seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
        }
```

**note:** ***if more code is needed, let me know i will edit the question***

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [MediaPlayer#prepareAsync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29).

> Prepares the player for playback, asynchronously. After setting the datasource and the display surface, you need to either call prepare() or prepareAsync(). For streams, you should call prepareAsync(), which returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been buffered.

Use this metod instead of `prepare`. You will by notified when media source is ready for playback via [MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html).